# Stripe inline form & disabled javascript

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, accessibility

Inline payment forms with Stripe require using Javascript in order to setup the form, request a token, and then submit the form with the token.

This is working just perfectly... But I couldn't find any fallback for **javascript-disabled** browsers.
Isn't it a significant accessibility issue ?

I assume that people who disabled javascript for performance/security reasons could re-enabled it temporarily it they do trust the seller, but what about blind people using adapted browsers without JS ?

Is there any workaround for having a Stripe embedded form without JS ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but what about blind people using adapted browsers without JS ?

I'm blind myself.

In fact, we generally use the same browsers as everybody else: Internet Explorer, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, ...
As in the general population, blind people using uncommon browsers are very rare, and those who do probably 1/have their reasons and 2/are better in understanding computers.

If you are wondering how we can use a "normal" browser, I suggest that you make a search about screen reader.

> Isn't it a significant accessibility issue ?

It is no longer. WCAG 1 state that an alternative without JavaScript should be provided.
At the time WCAG 1 has been written, JS wasn't so popular and so well supported.
So well, it was very important.

WCAG 2 no longer has this requirement.
However, obviously, you must ensure that all dynamic contents generated or managed by JS be always accessible.

If your page absolutely require JS and is totally unusable without it (it's becoming very common with SPA), it's still a good practice to indicate that JS is required, in case it is disabled. Use `<noscript>` for this.

Comment: +1 - just wanted to add that the only requirement / best practice you should have is to inform users that the page requires JavaScript to operate correctly if they have JavaScript disabled, just so that they understand what is happening.

Comment: When i was in school, i learned that we should always provide a JS alternative especially for accessibility purpose but it was indeed 12 years ago. Happy to hear that this is not relevant anymore...

Comment: Given that the browser was itself accessible, even back in the 2000s, JavaScript has never been inaccessible per ce. What is important is in fact what you do with it.
At that time, obviously, nobody had understood that. The main problem was the accessibility of the OS, the browser, and the scren reader. Basicly that meant Windows, IE and Jaws.

Fortunately things have evolved since. We have good screen readers on all major platforms (win/mac/iOS/android) and they work with all major browsers (IE/firefox/chrome/safari)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can use the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card_token). However this is a bad practice, though, and requires that your website and/or app meets a [stricter level of PCI compliance](https://stripe.com/docs/security#validating-pci-compliance)

Comment: Is it considered as a non-issue nowadays for Stripe not handling this natively ?